# RHEL6: system default font

Tags: rhel, xterm, urxvt

When I fire up urxvt or xterm, by default the font is a sans-serif monospace unaliased font. I would like to make this my font in other applications, but I can't find it in my system font list (i.e. I can't find it in the font list in gnome-control-center). I tried looking in `/etc/X11/Xresources` and `~/.Xresources`, but there are no fonts mentioned in either. Does anybody know how to determine what font this is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`xterm/urxvt` default to 'fixed` or whatever this has been aliased to. On my system (Arch):

```
grep -r '^fixed' /usr/share/fonts/
```

returns

```
/usr/share/fonts/cyrillic/fonts.alias:fixed  -misc-fixed-medium-r-semicondensed--13-120-75-75-c-60-koi8-r
/usr/share/fonts/misc/fonts.alias:fixed        -misc-fixed-medium-r-semicondensed--13-120-75-75-c-60-iso8859-1
```

So the font used in `xterm` is *Fixed Medium Semi-Condensed*. Here is a screen-shot with the font in `Font Viewer`, `xterm` and `gnome-terminal` below (the latter configured to use the same font):

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I actually managed to figure this out but I forgot I posted this topic, haha :) in any case I couldn't get gnome to recognize fixed (which, as it turns out, is an alias on my machine for another font) because it's a bitmap font.